# If $f \in \mathscr{F}_a$ with $a > 0$, then for any positive integer $n$, one has $f^{(n)} \in \mathscr{F}_b$ whenever $0 \leq b < a$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that if $f \in \mathscr{F}_a$ with $a > 0$, then for any positive integer $n$, one has $f^{(n)} \in \mathscr{F}_b$ whenever $0 \leq b < a$.

**My attempt at a solution:**

Well, we know that $f \in \mathscr{F}_a$ with $a > 0$ means that:

- $f$ is holomorphic in the horizontal strip $S_a = \{ x \in \mathbb{C}: |Im(z)| < a \}$
- $\exists A > 0$ such that $|f(x + iy)| \leq \frac{A}{1 + x^2}$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $|y| < a$

By the Cauchy inequalities, we also know that:

$$f^{(n)}(z) \leq \frac{n! ||f||_c}{R^n}$$

where $C$ is the boundary circle of some disc contained in our strip $S_a$.

We want to show that $f^{(n)}(z) \in \mathscr{F}_b$ for $0 \leq b < a$. That is, we want to show that:

1. $f$ is holomorphic in the horizontal strip $S_b = \{ x \in \mathbb{C}: |Im(z)| < b \}$
2. $\exists B > 0$ such that $|f(x + iy)| \leq \frac{B}{1 + x^2}$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $|y| < b$

I believe that (1) is immediate, as we know $S_b \subset S_a$, and $f$ has infinitely many complex derivatives in $S_a$, so thus $f^{(n)}$ is holomorphic in $S_b$. But how do I show that (2) is true? Thanks.